# Can I set max_retries for requests.request?

Tags: python, python-requests

The Python requests module is simple and elegant but one thing bugs me.
It is possible to get a *requests.exception.ConnectionError* with a message like:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: ...
```

This implies that requests can attempt to access the data several times. But there is not a single mention of this possibility anywhere in the docs. Looking at the source code I didn't find any place where I could alter the default (presumably 0) value.

So is it possible to somehow set the maximum number of retries for requests?

Comment: Any update on this with requests at 2.x? Would love a requests.get(url, max_retries=num_max_retries)) implementation.

Comment: @paragbaxi: and even better a `requests.get(url, max_retries=num_max_retries, dely_between_retries=3))`

Comment: @WoJ I took your examples and made it reality ;) in `just.get` and `just.post` in https://github.com/kootenpv/just

Comment: Useful article about retries with Requests: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests

Answer (score 234, accepted):

It is the underlying `urllib3` library that does the retrying. To set a different maximum retry count, use [alternative transport adapters](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters):

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://stackoverflow.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
```

The `max_retries` argument takes an integer or a [`Retry()` object](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry); the latter gives you fine-grained control over what kinds of failures are retried (an integer value is turned into a `Retry()` instance which only handles connection failures; errors after a connection is made are by default not handled as these could lead to side-effects).

---

*Old answer, predating the release of requests 1.2.1*:

The `requests` library doesn't really make this configurable, nor does it intend to (see [this pull request](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/1219)). Currently (requests 1.1), the retries count is set to 0. If you really want to set it to a higher value, you'll have to set this globally:

```
import requests

requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 5
```

This constant is not documented; use it at your own peril as future releases could change how this is handled.

**Update**: and this *did* change; in version 1.2.1 [the option to set the `max_retries` parameter](https://github.com/psf/requests/commit/36dcce1a06fe0a82d8522c7d4287fb3623722c6c) on the [`HTTPAdapter()` class](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter) was added, so that now you have to use alternative transport adapters, see above. The monkey-patch approach no longer works, unless you also patch the `HTTPAdapter.__init__()` defaults (very much not recommended).

Comment: @user136036: yes, adapters are looked up by longest prefix match; if you want this to apply to *all* urls then `http://` and `https://` are the minimal prefixes to use, see the documentation the answer links to.

Comment: Note that `HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5)` will only work for certain scenario. From [requests doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=max_retries#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter), `Note, this applies only to failed DNS lookups, socket connections and connection timeouts, never to requests where data has made it to the server. By default, Requests does not retry failed connections.` To force retry for any status codes, see @datashaman's answer below.

Comment: @StevenXu: yes, you can configure `Retry()` to alter what failure scenarios are retried.

Answer (score 487):

This will not only change the *max_retries* but also enable a backoff strategy which makes requests to all *http://* addresses sleep for a period of time before retrying (to a total of 5 times):

```
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry

s = requests.Session()

retries = Retry(total=5,
                backoff_factor=0.1,
                status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])

s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')
```

As per [documentation for `Retry`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry): if the backoff_factor is *0.1*, then sleep() will sleep for [0.05s, 0.1s, 0.2s, 0.4s, ...] between retries. It will also force a retry if the status code returned is *500*, *502*, *503* or *504*.

Various other options to `Retry` allow for more granular control:

- *total* – Total number of retries to allow.
- *connect* – How many connection-related errors to retry on.
- *read* – How many times to retry on read errors.
- *redirect* – How many redirects to perform.
- *method_whitelist* – Set of uppercased HTTP method verbs that we should retry on.
- *status_forcelist* – A set of HTTP status codes that we should force a retry on.
- *backoff_factor* – A backoff factor to apply between attempts.
- *raise_on_redirect* – Whether, if the number of redirects is exhausted, to raise a `MaxRetryError`, or to return a response with a response code in the *3xx* range.
- raise_on_status – Similar meaning to *raise_on_redirect*: whether we should raise an exception, or return a response, if status falls in *status_forcelist* range and retries have been exhausted.

<strike>**NB**: *raise_on_status* is relatively new, and has not made it into a release of urllib3 or requests yet.</strike> The *raise_on_status* keyword argument appears to have made it into the standard library at most in python version 3.6.

To make requests retry on specific HTTP status codes, use *status_forcelist*. For example, *status_forcelist=[503]* will retry on status code *503* (service unavailable).

By default, the retry only fires for these conditions:

- Could not get a connection from the pool.
- `TimeoutError`
- `HTTPException` raised (from *http.client* in Python 3 else *httplib*).
  This seems to be low-level HTTP exceptions, like URL or protocol not
  formed correctly.
- `SocketError`
- `ProtocolError`

Notice that these are all exceptions that prevent a regular HTTP response from being received. If **any** regular response is generated, no retry is done. Without using the *status_forcelist*, even a response with status 500 will not be retried.

To make it behave in a manner which is more intuitive for working with a remote API or web server, I would use the above code snippet, which forces retries on statuses *500*, *502*, *503* and *504*, all of which are not uncommon on the web and (possibly) recoverable given a big enough backoff period.

Comment: I am trying to implement your logic, but I dont know if it is working because the log just show one request even the res status is 503. How I can know if the retry is working? See the code: pastebin.com/rty4bKTw

Comment: The attached code works as expected. The trick is the *status_forcelist* parameter. This tells the urllib3 package to retry specific status codes. Code: http://pastebin.com/k2bFbH7Z

Comment: urllib3 does not (and should not) think that status 503 is an exception (by default).

Comment: Does this work with non-session actions (e.g. requests.post() ?)

Comment: @Connor no, the adapter is attached to the session.

Comment: urlib3.Retry is no longer part of requests. this have to imported directly. Suggested edit

Comment: @datashaman total=5 meaning for every not successful request it will request max for 5 times. Is that right?

Comment: Docs say: Set to 0 to fail on the first retry. So I'd assume that 1 would fail on the second retry, and so on. So `total=5` would fail on the 6th retry, probably before it attempts it.

Comment: How to use this mechanism based on response text? For example for those APIs which return 200 status code along with message "Please retry later."

Tried custom Session() with no luck: https://pastebin.com/tJumKGKN

Comment: How to retry connections when the server closes with no response? I.e. when the exception is `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. When you mention in the comments that this does not work for requests.post() - why is it so? (it works when I tried so I am confused)

Comment: @WoJ the original question was would it work with `requests.post`, which it won't. It will work with `s.post`, which is the session which has the adapter mounted to it. `requests.post` does not have an adapter mounted.

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský this does not handle non-HTTP response errors. you'd have to wrap the call to this in a try/except which retries a few times to handle connection errors.

Comment: allowed_methods=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']) for post

Comment: @datashaman , Can you guide me in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74000302/8519380

Answer (score 68):

Be careful, Martijn Pieters's answer isn't suitable for version 1.2.1+. You can't set it globally without patching the library.

You can do this instead:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://www.github.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
s.mount('https://www.github.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
```

Comment: Nice solution but note that there is no delay between retries. If you want to sleep between attempts, you will need to roll your own.

Comment: you can add timeout as well https://findwork.dev/blog/advanced-usage-python-requests-timeouts-retries-hooks/ see this

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K great article!

Answer (score 38):

After struggling a bit with some of the answers here, I found a library called [backoff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backoff) that worked better for my situation.  A basic example:

```
import backoff

@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    requests.exceptions.RequestException,
    max_tries=5,
    giveup=lambda e: e.response is not None and e.response.status_code < 500
)
def publish(self, data):
    r = requests.post(url, timeout=10, json=data)
    r.raise_for_status()
```

I'd still recommend giving the library's native functionality a shot, but if you run into any problems or need broader control, backoff is an option.

Comment: great library, thank you! I needed this functionality for something else than `requests`, so this works perfectly!

Answer (score 14):

You can use the requests library to accomplish all in one go.
The following code will retry 3 times if you receive 429,500,502,503 or 504 status code, each time with a longer delay set through "backoff_factor". See https://findwork.dev/blog/advanced-usage-python-requests-timeouts-retries-hooks/ for a nice tutorial.

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=3,
    backoff_factor=1,
    status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    method_whitelist=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

response = http.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php")
```

Comment: From my tests, you don't need to include 429 on `status_forcelist` because it is already automatically retried.

Comment: @PabloCastellano only if you don’t override `status_forcelist`.

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner way to gain higher control might be to package the retry stuff into a function and make that function retriable using a decorator and whitelist the exceptions.

I have created the same here:
http://www.praddy.in/retry-decorator-whitelisted-exceptions/

Reproducing the code in that link :

```
def retry(exceptions, delay=0, times=2):
"""
A decorator for retrying a function call with a specified delay in case of a set of exceptions

Parameter List
-------------
:param exceptions:  A tuple of all exceptions that need to be caught for retry
                                    e.g. retry(exception_list = (Timeout, Readtimeout))
:param delay: Amount of delay (seconds) needed between successive retries.
:param times: no of times the function should be retried


"""
def outer_wrapper(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        final_excep = None  
        for counter in xrange(times):
            if counter > 0:
                time.sleep(delay)
            final_excep = None
            try:
                value = function(*args, **kwargs)
                return value
            except (exceptions) as e:
                final_excep = e
                pass #or log it

        if final_excep is not None:
            raise final_excep
    return inner_wrapper

return outer_wrapper

@retry(exceptions=(TimeoutError, ConnectTimeoutError), delay=0, times=3)
def call_api():
```

Comment: is this for python 2.0?

Comment: This link is down now.