# Python requests equivalent for cURL's --location-trusted

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, http-authentication

With cURL, I can do `--location-trusted` to allow sending the name+password to all hosts the site may redirect to (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--location-trusted).

Can I do something similar in Python with the requests library?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use libcurl (which you legitimately may!), you'll need to pass it the [`CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH.html) option.

While the doc page itself doesn't mention it, this is the libcurl equivalent of the command line `--location-trusted` flag. See [the CVE page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/CVE-2018-1000007.html) where they introduced `--location-trusted` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` will automatically take care of redirects:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history
So, this should be a good place to start (if you haven't already gone through it):
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: But when the redirect happens, the username and password pair is not passed over. So, I'm getting authentication issue when redirected.

Comment: @jianweichuah were you able to find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`urllib3.util.Retry`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry) object to tell requests to not remove the `Authorization` header when it has to retry a request because it was redirected.

```
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry

s = requests.Session()
# Default is {'Authorization'}
retries = Retry(remove_headers_on_redirect=set())
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

s.get("http://httpstat.us/301", auth=('user', 'password'))
```

Comment: I have no idea if this works, I just read [this github issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1316), this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267409/how-to-implement-retry-mechanism-into-python-requests-library) and the docs I linked.