# How do I know what error my program is making that makes it stuck while downloading images from web and how to handle this in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am downloading few images from a website that has its images url in sequence format.

Every time I run the loop it gets stuck at any random point for example after 50 images or sometimes after downloading 70 images and `it doesn't throw any type of error and just get stuck`. How can I handle this to make sure I download everything in 1 go without any stops ?

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import time

for i in range(1,240):
    filepath = r"C:\Users\....\Image collector\\"
    filename = f'{i:03}'+".jpg"
    fullpath = filepath+filename
    print(fullpath)

    url = "https://www.somerandomxyzwebsite.com/abc_"+f'{i:03}'+".jpg"

    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullpath)          

    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)

    except URLError:
        print("Server down or incorrect domain")

print('done')
```

Can I include a condition (if execution time > 1 min) then hit the same url again. Is it a right approach or is there other approach to handle this situation ?

Comment: I would set a timeout value, and a retry value. You probably should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267409/how-to-implement-retry-mechanism-into-python-requests-library?rq=1  . Hope it helps

Comment: They may be noticing your rapid connections to their webserver as malicious traffic, or even just as web scraping, and [tarpitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) your connections. You may want to build some `time.sleep` or other delays in your script so that you don't look like an attacker and/or use up all their bandwidth

Comment: @Flo thanks this is helpful

Comment: @G.Anderson I don't think this website is capable of tracking. Its a very small level website. 
I think the problem is that the server is not capable enough to handle so many requests continuously. So how should I re-request from the point where it has got stuck. I could be wrong here as I am an amateur in coding/tech space

Comment: You may be correct, and @Flo gave you the link that could help in that case. But in general, smaller websites are hosted by companies that often have DDOS protection which may have the effect I described. And if not, then it's still a good idea to include some time between requests so that you don't overwhelm the servers for a small site (even if it's just for the benefit of normal users of the site, or being polite to the site's owner(s))

Comment: @G.Anderson yes this could be the case as well, thank you for educating me on this.
And i knew about time delay but i wanted to understand how could I re-request or over come this without time delay and this is where link shared by Flo will help.