# Python request loop, retry if status code not 200

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I do a loop of requests and unfortunately sometimes there happens a server timeout. Thats why I want to check the status code first and if it is not 200 I want to go back and repeat the last request until the status code is 200. An example of the code looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(table)):
        var = table.iloc[i]
        url = 'http://example.request.com/var/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
        else:
            "go back to response"
```

I am appending the response data of every i, so I would like to go back as long as the response code is 200 and then go on with the next i in the loop.
Is there any easy solution?

Comment: Also: `url = "http://example.request.com/{0:}/".format(var)`.

Comment: You might want to check that you actually get a timeout, either locally or remotely, before hammering the server...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(table)):
        var = table.iloc[i]
        url = 'http://example.request.com/var/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        while response.status_code != 200:
            response = requests.get(url)     
        data = response.json()
```

Comment: A more robust solution to the same problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636367/195964

Answer (score 2):

I made a small example, used an infinite loop and used break to demonstrate when the status code is = 200

```
while True:
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # found code
        print('found exemple')
        break
```