# Retry mechanism for my web crawler script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, url, networking

So, I am trying to make a website crawler which would retrieve **all links** within the site and print them to the **console** and also redirect the links to a **text file** using a **python script**.

This script will take in the **URL of the website** you want to retrieve links from and the no.of URLs to be followed from the main page and the **maximum number of URLs** to be retrieved and then using the functions `crawl()`, `is_valid()` and `get_all_website_links()` it retrieves the URLs. It also separates **external links and internal links** through the `get_all_website_links()` function.

So far I have been **successful** with the retrieving and printing and redirecting the links to the text file using the script but I faced a problem when the server **refuses** to connect. It **stops** the link retrieval and **ends** the execution.

What I want my script to do is to **retry** a specified number of times and **continue** to the next link if it **fails** even after retrying.

I tried to implement this mechanism by myself but I **did not** get any idea.

I'm appending my python script below for your better understanding.

An **elaborate** explanation with implementation would be deeply appreciated!

Pardon me if my grammar is bad ;)

Thanks for your time :)

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import colorama
import sys


sys.setrecursionlimit(99999999)


print("WEBSITE CRAWLER".center(175,"_"))
print("\n","="*175)
print("\n\n\n\nThis program does not tolerate faults!\nPlease type whatever you are typing correctly!\nIf you think you have made a mistake please close the program and reopen it!\nIf you proceed with errors the program will crash/close!\nHelp can be found in the README.txt file!\n\n\n")
print("\n","="*175)


siteurl = input("Enter the address of the site (Please don't forget https:// or http://, etc. at the front!) :")
max_urls = int(input("Enter the number of urls you want to crawl through the main page : "))
filename = input("Give a name for your text file (Don't append .txt at the end!) : ")


# init the colorama module
colorama.init()
GREEN = colorama.Fore.GREEN
MAGENTA = colorama.Fore.MAGENTA
RESET = colorama.Fore.RESET


# initialize the set of links (unique links)
internal_urls = set()
external_urls = set()


def is_valid(url):
    """
    Checks whether `url` is a valid URL.
    """
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)


def get_all_website_links(url):
    """
    Returns all URLs that is found on `url` in which it belongs to the same website
    """
    # all URLs of `url`
    urls = set()
    # domain name of the URL without the protocol
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href == "" or href is None:
            # href empty tag
            continue
        # join the URL if it's relative (not absolute link)
        href = urljoin(url, href)
        parsed_href = urlparse(href)
        # remove URL GET parameters, URL fragments, etc.
        href = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
        if not is_valid(href):
            # not a valid URL
            continue
        if href in internal_urls:
            # already in the set
            continue
        if domain_name not in href:
            # external link
            if href not in external_urls:
                print(f"{MAGENTA} [!] External link: {href}{RESET}")
                with open(filename+".txt","a") as f:
                    print(f"{href}",file = f)
                external_urls.add(href)
            continue
        print(f"{GREEN}[*] Internal link: {href}{RESET}")
        with open(filename+".txt","a") as f:
            print(f"{href}",file = f)
        urls.add(href)
        internal_urls.add(href)
    return urls



# number of urls visited so far will be stored here
total_urls_visited = 0

def crawl(url, max_urls=50000):
    """
    Crawls a web page and extracts all links.
    You'll find all links in `external_urls` and `internal_urls` global set variables.
    params:
        max_urls (int): number of max urls to crawl, default is 30.
    """
    global total_urls_visited
    total_urls_visited += 1
    links = get_all_website_links(url)
    for link in links:
        if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
            break
        crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)



        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawl(siteurl,max_urls)
    print("[+] Total External links:", len(external_urls))
    print("[+] Total Internal links:", len(internal_urls))
    print("[+] Total:", len(external_urls) + len(internal_urls))
    input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement retry mechanism into python requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267409/how-to-implement-retry-mechanism-into-python-requests-library)

Comment: @Maurice Meyer The thing is that i'm using `BeautifulSoup4` to retrieve the URLs but the post which you asked me to refer answers for the library `requests`.Anyway, thanks for your time

Comment: I have solved the dilemma myself! Thanks for the co-operation!