# Python 2.7: Request with retries does not function

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am testing with a url that will return 503 and would want the script to request the URL with a `backoff_factor` of 1 with  `max _retries` function. Base on my 8 times retries, theoretically the request was supposed to spend at least 64 s for the request but it just straight away print the response 503 and I do not think it actually retries for 8 times. I even increase `backoff_factor` to 20 and still instantly print out response 503

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import requests

url = 'http://httpstat.us/503'
s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=8, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[ 502, 503, 504 ])
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response = s.get(url)
print response
```

I have been checking other post and try with `s.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))` with similar result.
How to let the script really retries 8 times and confirm it actually retries?
Please advise if the solution works for `HTTP` and `https`

When I call retries

```
>>> retries
Retry(total=8, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
```

Is the input correct?
I base on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636367/5730859 solution and but it does not seems to retry. Can anyone help?

Comment: 1) the server will have a much faster response time when it errors or there is a client-side deformity. 2) Assuming the server is setup correctly, 503 means the service/endpoint is unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

Updating to newest comments. Instead of using that urllib3 function, use your own:

```
>>> def test():
    return requests.get("http://httpstat.us/503").status_code

>>> def main():
    total_retries = 0
    code = test()
    while code == 503 or 502 or 504:
        total_retries+=1
        if total_retries > 8:
            print("8 retries hit")
            break
        code = test()

        
>>> main()
8 retries hit
>>>
```

This will stop once it hits 8 retries with the 503, 504, 502 code(s).

Comment: Nope. I am using 503 as an example. The URL just an example. You can use any URL that return 503. I mean the script does not retries even it is error 503, what is the problem?

Comment: If it is just an "example" problem then you must show the URL you are requesting. That is a server-side error, so it is not the client but the server that is "messing up". Read what i said, what you are doing really makes no sense.

Comment: there is no retries for this confirm 503 with this URL `http://httpstat.us/503`

Comment: take a look at the new answer

Comment: Could your solution base on my snippet? The solution you provided I have tried previously but I need something more pythonic

Comment: when you run my code, do you get any retries? retries suppose to take times instead to get 503 instantly

Comment: you are not making any sense at all. You are importing the requests library to use another library's functions. I gave you a working solution for ```requests```.

Comment: your solution is not the elegant way.