# Python Requests: why do I get the error "get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" when I only have two arguments?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-504

I'm trying to implement error-handling of 504 responses for my Requests statement when I query an API.  I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267409/how-to-implement-retry-mechanism-into-python-requests-library), and am attempting to implement the solution given in the most-voted answer.

My code keeps failing with the error `get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.  In my code (below), I'm only passing `get()` two arguments, though.  Where am I going wrong?

Here's the full error TraceBack:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
  File " ... ", line 113, in my_function
    s.get("https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json", payload)
  File " ... ",  line 158, in <module>
    d = my_function(l)
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My code:

```
payload = {
   "x": coordinate[0],
   "y": coordinate[1],
   "wkid": 4326,
   "units": "Meter",
   "includeDate": "false",
}
s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(
   total=10,
   backoff_factor=1,
   status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504],
)
s.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
s.get("https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json", payload)
```

My previous code that didn't make use of `Session()` or `mount()` worked, so does `Session()` add some data behind the scenes to the `get()` request that I'm overlooking?

Here's my previous code, fwiw:

```
payload = {
   "x": coordinate[0],
   "y": coordinate[1],
   "wkid": 4326,
   "units": "Meter",
   "includeDate": "false",
}
r = requests.get("https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json", payload)
```

Comment: You're right, there are only two arguments here, so the problem must be somewhere else.  Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

Only (as far as I can tell) `requests.get` allows you to pass the parameters as a positional argument. You must use a keyword argument for `Session.get`.

```
s.get("https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json", params=payload)
```

(The two allowed positional arguments are the `Session` object `s` implicit to the method call and the URL; the payload is the 3rd.)

Comment: Wow, that was it!  What a simple thing for me to have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

`s.get` is an instance method, so the first positional argument is in fact `self` which is implicitly passed when the method is called. See below:

```py
class foo:
    def bar(self, a, b):
        return a+b
        
foo().bar(1,2,3)
# TypeError: ’bar’ takes three
# arguments, but four were passed:
#    self, 1, 2, and 3
```