# python request error handling

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing some small python app which uses requests to get and post data to an html page.

now the problem I am having is that if I can't reach the html page the code stops with a max retries exceeded. I want to be able to do some things if I can't reach the server.

is such a thing possible?

here is sample code:

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1/"
req = requests.get(url)
if req.status_code == 304:
    #do something
elif req.status_code == 404:
    #do something else
# etc etc 

# code here if server can`t be reached for whatever reason
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to handle the exception `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, like so:

```
try:
    req = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    # Do stuff here
```

Comment: If I want to catch all exception, not just connectionerror can I remove the stuff after except? Thank you for your quick answer

Comment: Sure; but, generally speaking, I prefer to handle different classes of exception in different ways, so you might want to think carefully about how you apply that logic.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set a suitable timeout when catching `ConnectionError`:

```
url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

try:
    req = requests.get(url, timeout=2)  #2 seconds timeout
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    # Couldn't connect
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request) if you want to change the number of retries.