# Retry network requests in Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
s = requests.session()
s.get('http://foo.bar/')
s.post('http://foo.bar/')
```

The above code stops execution if the `get` or `post` method fail due to any reason. What I want it to do is that it should retry the `get` or `post` method until there is no exception.

Is there a way to put a wrapper on the `requests.session()` object so that all calls to its methods do a retry on any error?

I'm a newbie to Python so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Why not retrying in a loop?

Comment: Related: [Can I set max\_retries for requests.request?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15431044)

Comment: How can I retry for all my get and post calls? I just want a single retry loop

Comment: @Zuck: what do you mean? You want to retry them *as a group*? Start from the beginning when any of them fails?

Comment: It is rare to occure temporal failure for accessing web server. Whay do you think that retry are effective to solve your problem? What situation do you imagine that a failure without exception?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have different functions which call the get and post methods on the `s` object many times in the code. Can I add the retry loop just once for all those somehow?

Comment: @Zuck: yes, that is what the code in the other question **does**. It mounts a new HTTP adapter with a retry count. It'll retry connections up to that many times. *Each time you use the session*.

Comment: @Fumu7 The server gets down & my code fails.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want infinite retries with a interval that I can set. For 1st retry- 10 seconds, 2nd - 20 seconds, 10th retry - 10 minutes so on.

Comment: Also there are millions of subdomains. (something like *.herokuapp.com) That solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Zuck: then you'd need to program that yourself; we can help you when you've come up with an attempt. A backing-off-retry feature is too broad to go code up in an answer.

Comment: @Zuck: the prefix can be an empty string; e.g. apply to everything. Or use a protocol; the prefix `http://` applies to all HTTP connections.

Comment: @Zuck: the generic name for what you want is a exponential backoff retry. A quick google turns up [`retrying`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much. I think I'd do with the empty string now.

Comment: @Zuck: I'd stay with `http://` in this case; by default there are two mounts, for `http://` and `https://`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I need both http and https. Do I need adapters for them each or will the empty string do?

Comment: @Zuck: I *suspect* that separate adapters are registered to prevent HTTP connections being reused for HTTPS URLs. You can probably get away with the empty prefix, but perhaps registering two adapters is prudent here.