# How to send one more request when failed for once with python-requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a url fetcher. When I send a request like:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://example.com")
```

Sometimes an error like this occurs:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine(""''''"))
```

But when I try one more time, it fixes. So I would like to send one more time when such an error occurs again. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could increase the [maximum retry count from the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request).

Comment: You might be better using a try/except and retrying after catching the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the request again when the exception is raised.

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com"

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except requests.exception.ConnectionError:
    response = requests.get(url)
```