# How to Catch a 503 Error and retry request

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I'm using `grequests` to make about 10,000 calls, but some of these calls return as `503`. This problem goes away if I don't queue all 10,000 calls at once. Breaking it into groups of 1000 seems to do the trick. However I was wondering if there's a way to catch this `503` error and just retry the `request`.

This is how I'm calling and combining the threads:

```
import grequests
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header) for u in urls)
response = grequests.map(rs)
```

I know this is really vague, but I don't even know if this is possible using `grequests`.

I naivley tried

```
import grequests
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header) for u in urls)
time.sleep(1)
response = grequests.map(rs)
```

But this does nothing to slow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try using event hooks to catch the error and re-launch the requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks

```
 import grequests

 def response_handler(response):
     if response.status_code == '503':
         print('error.503')

 rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header, hooks = dict('response' : response_handler)) for u in urls)
 response = grequests.map(rs)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the general methods described at 
 [Can I set max_retries for requests.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request) to configure requests and urllib3 to do retries, assuming that grequests lets you customize the underlying connections or requests.