# Django system check stuck on unreachable url

Tags: django

In my project I have `requests` library that sends `POST` request. Url for that request is hardcoded in function, which is accessed from `views.py`.

The problem is that when I dont have internet connection, or host, on which url is pointing, is down, I cant launch developer server, it gets stuck on `Performing system check`. However, if I comment the line with url, or change it to guarantee working host, check is going well.

What is good workaround here ?

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    s = Sync()
    s.do()
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

**sync.py**

```
class Sync:
    def do(self):
        reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(is_synced=False)
        for reservation in reservations:
            serializer = ReservationPKSerializer(reservation)
            dictionary = {'url': 'url', 'hash': 'hash', 'json': serializer.data}
            encoded_data = json.dumps(dictionary)
            r = requests.post('http://gservice.ca29983.tmweb.ru/gdocs/do.php', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=encoded_data)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                reservation.is_synced = True
                reservation.save()
```

Comment: A try catch would be good workaround with catching exception HTTPError

Comment: tried like this http://imgur.com/a/BCH9g but it didn't help, still stuck on check

Comment: Can you post some code of views.py which contains the code you mentioned. It might help us to find the problem

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

It might appear to be stuck because `requests` automatically retries the connection a few times. Try reducing the retry count to 0 or 1 with:

[Can I set max_retries for requests.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request)