# Python thread retry every X seconds up to Y minutes

Tags: python, multithreading, retry-logic

I'm trying to implement the client-server architecture in Python, where I have:

- Server application
- List of clients, who can subscribe to updates via API (sending POST requests to /subscribe endpoint).

It works fine. On the server side, I have a list of subscriber's URLs.

The main idea is to send requests from the server to all subscribed clients every X seconds (something similar to monitoring system).

I'm trying to do this part using threads:

```
class Monitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Monitor, self).__init__()
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def send_notifications(self, subscribers):
        for subscriber in subscribers:
            request.post(subscriber["url"], json=subscriber["data"], timeout=0.5)

    def run(self):
        subscribers = get_subscribers()  # getting list of subscribers via API call.
        while True:
            self.send_notifications(subscribers)
            time.sleep(Y)
```

More or less it works, but I need to improve it a little.
The expected behaviour is:
The server should send notifications every X seconds to each subscribed client. If sending the notification to some client fails for Y minutes(5 minutes for example) it should unsubscribe this unresponsive client.

Is there some best practices for this?

Comment: Are you confident that your server will be able to make outgoing TCP connections to the clients?  (in across-the-Internet scenarios, most clients will be firewalled and/or NAT'd, making it difficult or impossible for them to accept an incoming TCP connection from a server)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, currently it's not an issue. I just want to add this logic to unsubscribe clients, which were turned off at all.

Comment: Well, timing out unresponsive clients is a pretty common thing to do; I can't think of any reason not to do it.  The only potential "gotcha" would be accidentally timing out a client that was still alive, but had an intermittent network connection; in that case you'd probably want to augment the client with some mechanism for realizing when it had been unilaterally unsubscribed and resubscribing again once its network connectivity had been restored.

Comment: If you are using the `requests` package (which it looks like you are), I'd recommend looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35504626/955340 and this documentation: http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html for implementing exponential backoff (retrying less and less frequently till you either manage, or the timeout is reached).