# How do I use a non-exponential backoff strategy for retries in python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to make use of the requests module backoff strategy outlined at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35504626/1021819, the code reproduced from that answer being:

```py
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()

retries = Retry(total=5,
                backoff_factor=0.1,
                status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])

s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')
```

[This link gives further useful info: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests]

According to the documentation for backoff_factor at https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry,

> A backoff factor to apply between attempts after the second try (most errors are resolved immediately by a second try without a delay). urllib3 will sleep for:
>   `{backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total retries} - 1))`
>   seconds. If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then sleep() will sleep for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, …] between retries. It will never be longer than Retry.BACKOFF_MAX.

**How can I elegantly implement a non-exponential backoff e.g. linear?**

Thanks as ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was deep in enemy territory, I ended up superclassing `Retry` and overloading `Retry.get_backoff_time()`. The new class `MyRetry` now takes an optional lambda specifying how to calculate the backoff time.

```py
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from itertools import takewhile


def linear_backoff(backoff_factor, consecutive_errors_len):
    return backoff_factor * float(consecutive_errors_len - 1)

class MyRetry(Retry):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.backoff_func = kwargs.pop('backoff_func', None)
        super(MyRetry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_backoff_time(self):
        """ Formula for computing the current backoff
        :rtype: float
        """
        # We want to consider only the last consecutive errors sequence (Ignore redirects).
        consecutive_errors_len = len(
            list(
                takewhile(lambda x: x.redirect_location is None, reversed(self.history))
            )
        )
        if consecutive_errors_len <= 1:
            return 0

        if self.backoff_func is not None:
            backoff_value = self.backoff_func(self.backoff_factor, consecutive_errors_len)
        else:
            backoff_value = self.backoff_factor * (2 ** (consecutive_errors_len - 1))
        return min(self.BACKOFF_MAX, backoff_value)

retries = MyRetry(total=5,
                 backoff_factor=0.1,
                 status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],backoff_func=lambda x,y:linear_backoff(x,y))

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')
```

Hey Presto!

The lambda is probably not necessary. It would be nice if the original Retry class could be made to take a lambda anyway.