# How to retry python requests.get without using sessions

Tags: python, session, python-requests, request, retry-logic

I want to retry the python requests.get(). I know we can do it with sessions but in a specific case I need to retry the requests.get() only so I wanted to know how do that? Is there any parameter like in session that we can pass?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request

Comment: I can not find any solution without using session?

Comment: See in answer..

Answer (score 2):

you can use [backoff](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) library, I'm using it and I think that it's a cleaner solution than adapters and sessions

A basic example:

```
import backoff

@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    requests.exceptions.RequestException,
    max_tries=5,
    giveup=lambda e: e.response is not None and e.response.status_code < 500
)
def publish(self, data):
    r = requests.post(url, timeout=10, json=data)
    r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Why is it a cleaner solution?