# How to implement retry with requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

[image]So i have this bit of code

```
statssession = requests.Session()
getstats = statssession.get('https://api.hypixel.net/player',
                                                params={'key': random.choice([key, key2]), 'uuid': playeruuid},
                                                timeout=10).json()
```

I'm completely new to python with no OOP experience and this bit of code throws a random time out exception for read randomly. What I want is when it throws that exception to not just break my code but retry the request instead preferably with the library from requests itself but I have no idea how to do it so here I'm asking, any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set max\_retries for requests.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request)

Comment: yeah it did to an extent thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the API incorrectly: https://api.hypixel.net/#section/Authentication/ApiKey

Try setting the key into the `requests.Session` headers:

```py
statssession = requests.Session()
statssession.headers["API-Key"] = random.choice([key, key2])
```

To try again after timeout, you can use a `try except` block:

```py
for _ in range(5):
    try:
        getstats = statssession.get(
            'https://api.hypixel.net/player',
            params = {'uuid': playeruuid},
            timeout=10).json()
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        continue
```

Or you can set retries within `urllib3`, used by `requests`, as outlined here: [Can I set max_retries for requests.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15431044/2449857)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i'm using more than just 2 api keys and i've made it so if those 2 api keys hit a rate limit it switches to other 2