# REQUESTS Maximum number of attempts with a waiting time and in case of failure, give a message in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, concurrent.futures, python-requests-html

the situation is that sometimes a request does not load or gets stuck in Python,   in case that happens or any error occurs, I would like to retry it "n" times and wait up to a maximum of 3 seconds for each one and in case the attempts are over tell me a message that f"Could not process {type_1} and {type_2}". Everything runs in parallel with concurrent.futures. Could you help me with that?

```
import Requests
import concurrent.futures
import json

data = [['PEN','USD'],['USD','EUR']]

def currency(element):

  type_1 =element[0]
  type_2 = element[1]

  s =  requests.Session()
  url = f'https://usa.visa.com/cmsapi/fx/rates?amount=1&fee=0&utcConvertedDate=07%2F26%2F2022&exchangedate=07%2F26%2F2022&fromCurr={type_1}&toCurr={type_2}'
  a = s.get(url)
  response = json.loads(a)
  value = response["convertedAmount"]

  return value

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
      results = executor.map(
                currency, data)
for value in results:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost there. Here, I modified a few things:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

import requests


def convert_currency(tup):
    from_currency, to_currency = tup
    url = (
        "https://usa.visa.com/cmsapi/fx/rates?amount=1&fee=0"
        "&utcConvertedDate=07%2F26%2F2022&exchangedate=07%2F26%2F2022&"
        f"fromCurr={from_currency}&toCurr={to_currency}"
    )
    session = requests.Session()
    for _ in range(3):
        try:
            response = session.get(url, timeout=3)
            if response.ok:
                return response.json()["convertedAmount"]
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
            time.sleep(3)
    return f"Could not process {from_currency} and {to_currency}"


data = [["VND", "XYZ"], ['PEN','USD'], ["ABC", "XYZ"], ['USD','EUR'], ["USD", "XXX"]]
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(convert_currency, data)
for value in results:
    print(value)
```

## Notes

- I retried 3 times (see the for loop)
- Use `timeout=` to specify the time out (in seconds)
- The `.ok` attribute will tell if the call was successful
- No need to import `json` as the response object can JSON decode with the `.json()` method
- You might experiment between `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` to see which one performs better

Comment: It's amazing but is there any possibility to improve it by using retries = Retry() instead of a loop?

Comment: Sometimes i had requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='usa.visa.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cmsapi/fx/rates?amount=1&fee=0&utcConvertedDate=08%2F01%2F2022&exchangedate=08%2F01%2F2022&fromCurr=IDR&toCurr=MOP (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027829FAC370>, 'Connection to usa.visa.com timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))

Comment: What is `Retry()`?

Comment: I have added `try/except` block to handle `requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout` error.

Comment: I saw something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request . it seems to me that Retry retries it without a try except, that's new to me too