# Clean way to pass different parameters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a wrapper function around `requests.post()` which implements retries in case when the call raises an exception. Somethingl like

```
def http_post(endpoint, headers=headers, payload=payload):
    ...
    try:
        response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=payload)
    ...
```

The problem is that some of the wrapped calls are of form

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)
```

whereas others are

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, json=data)
```

I could pass a a flag indicating the type of the third parameter or maybe try using **kwargs combined with exec but it appears messy.

Is there a way of doing it cleanly?

Comment: How do you know which form to use?  Where is `data` (the variable, not the keyword) defined?

Comment: `def http_post(endpoint, headers=headers, **kwargs):` would be enough

Comment: Consider taking a look at `Retry` before implementing your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35504626/4583620.

Comment: `**kwargs` is how problems like this are normally solved. This is exactly the kind of thing it was designed for.

Comment: you can use `**kwargs`, you don't need `exec` at all, just `def http(*args, **kwargs) -> : ...` then `requests.post(*args, **kwargs)` but just remember you should probably be catching a specific `requests.exceptions.RequestException` exception, not a bare `except` clause